# Why is "taking first n elements from an unsorted Map" meaningless?

Tags: scala, sortedmap

With reference to the tutorial:
https://hello-scala.com/240-collections-maps.html
Please locate:
"Note that the last example probably only makes sense for a sorted Map."
"the last example" in the above statement:

```
val sortedMap = Map(
    1 -> "a", 
    2 -> "b", 
    3 -> "c",
    4 -> "d"
)
sortedMap.take(2) // Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)
```

According to the above statement, Map.take(2) makes sense only when the Map is sorted.

```
val unSortedMap = Map(
    2 -> "b", 
    1 -> "a", 
    4 -> "d",
    3 -> "c"
)
unSortedMap.take(2) // Map(2 -> b, 1 -> a)
```

Question 1: Doesn't unSortedMap.take(2) make sense?
Question 2: If the answer to Q1 is no, why?

Comment: What would be the purpose of taking two random elements from an unsorted `Map`?

Comment: If the map is UNsorted, you can't take two _first_ elements, just two _some_ elements, as there's no ordering between them.

Comment: I apologize that I asked such a question.
My problem is that I only learn how to use the method but do not think why I use the method.

Comment: The very idea of "first" is meaningless without an order. You cannot take the first two elements because there are no first two elements, the concept of "first" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is referring to the literal `SortedMap` class. In a `SortedMap`, the entries are sorted by their keys. A `SortedMap` initialized with your data will *always* have the order `SortedMap(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d")`, because that's the only way for the keys to be sorted. For a plain `Map`, the order is not guaranteed. In particular, for `SortedMap`, `take` respects `==`: if `xs == ys` then `xs.take(n) == ys.take(n)`. But for `Map`, your example shows that's not true. Since a `Map` is "supposed" to be an unordered collection of mappings, you're not supposed to depend on its "order". Notice that if you extend your maps to 6 elements, their order completely changes, because of implementation details of the library. It only makes sense to use `take` on a generic `Map` if you truly don't care which mappings you get out. E.g. it would be acceptable if you were "splitting" the map so you could operate on its pieces in parallel, or if you're "chunking" it so you can serialize it, but you can't use `take` for "logical" operations, like adding a bunch of mappings to a `Map` and expecting them to come back out in the order you put them in.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the keys is an unsorted Map is irrelevant. Two maps are the same if they have the same elements whatever order they were added:

```
val mapA = Map(
  4 -> "d",
  3 -> "c",
  2 -> "b",
  1 -> "a",
)

val mapB = Map(
  1 -> "a",
  2 -> "b",
  3 -> "c",
  4 -> "d",
)

val same = mapA == mapB // true
val diff = mapA.take(2) == mapB.take(2) // false or possibly true
```

So you can't tell which elements will be returned by `take`.

Comment: Or, in other words: you cannot take the first two elements because there *are no* "first" elements. The entire concept of "first" is meaningless if you don't have an order in the first place.